# How do you say "longest enduring" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

I think the translation might be:

> mas largo duradero

Which I guess would literally mean "most long enduring".

> mas duradero

Maybe would be "most enduring".

I'm hoping for "longest enduring."

Comment: A lo mejor **la más antigua**; / **el más antiguo** Can you put it in a context?

Comment: The longest enduring political party in the country.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way to translate that kind of English construction (adjective + present participle) into Spanish. You will have to use a periphrasis, that is, to rephrase it. Something like

- *el partido político de más larga trayectoria del país*
- *el partido político que ha existido por más tiempo en el país*

*Duradero* is not the word you're looking for; it means something that is capable of lasting, or that has shown that it can last, but it doesn't really belong with *partido político* (it does belong with building materials, or with some abstractions like *paz* "peace").